# Почему данное выражение не работает в таком виде?

Tags: c++

Есть функция которая преобразовывает элемент enum class в std::string.
Допустим:

```
const std::string &getString(const numeration& l_enum)
{
    return (a > b)
        ? mass[static_cast<int>(l_enum)].m_name
        : "";
}
```

Данный код неверный. Почему?

Почему следующий код верен?
Правильный код:

```
const std::string &getString(const numeration& l_enum)
{
    static std::string emp = "";
    return (a > b)
        ? mass[static_cast<int>(l_enum)].m_name
        : emp;
}
```

Comment: А какая ошибка возникает в первом случае?

Comment: Потому что  строковой литерал  " ... "  имеет тип const char*, и получается в тернарной операции два разных типа

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, нет, будет создан временный объект типа std::string, никаких "разных типов" там нет.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, читайте здесь: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other

Comment: Попробовал в онлайн компиляторе : [http://cpp.sh/8m2m2](http://cpp.sh/8m2m2) , работают оба варианта... @Rundogie Rundogie , нужны остальные части программы, в частности, что такое `m_name` и `mass`

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, еще раз повторяю - я не удалял свой ответ, Вы можете лично в этом убедиться, опустив глаза немного ниже - в раздел ответов. "При этом грубо выражаясь" - Вам не стыдно? Я ничего грубого Вам не писал, в отличие от Вас - Вы называете меня "красавщик", и у Вас еще хватает наглости говорить, что я груб в общении с Вами? Вопрос риторический, лично мне и так все предельно ясно. На этой ноте завершаю с Вами диалог.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, Да,действительно!

Comment: @zcorvid, значит этот компилятор исправляет ошибки за программиста.

Comment: @Юрий Козлов, функция просто не работает.

Comment: @Юрий Козлов, вызывает исключение.

Comment: @RundogieRundogie Не уверен, что смогу помочь, но все же спрошу: какое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> следующий код верен

Код:

```
const std::string &getString(const numeration& l_enum)
{
    std::string emp = "";
    return (a > b)
        ? mass[static_cast<int>(l_enum)].m_name
        : emp;
}
```

А почему Вы решили, что он верен? Вы явно возвращаете ссылку на локальную переменную, после возврата последняя уже не существует, и в результате у Вас остается ссылка на уничтоженный объект.

В первом случае Вы возвращаете ссылку на временный объект, который будет уничтожен после выполнения оператора `return`.

P.S. У Вас скорее всего ничего не поломается потому что компилятор обеспечивает временным объектам столь же долгую жизнь, как и инициализированным ими ссылкам (const).

Comment: Исправил код. Когда я говорил что данный код верен я имел ввиду что функция работает корректно в таком виде при условии что a>b а в другом виде выше показанном функция не работает вообще.

Comment: @RundogieRundogie, я прокомментировал тот код, который Вы предоставили. Я понял, что Вы имеете в виду, но в данном случае "код работает" не означает, что он правильный. Теперь, когда Вы поправили код и добавили `static`, функцию можно считать корректной - при выходе из функции объект не уничтожится (компилятор создаст область хранения в памяти, и переменная "проживет" до конца работы программы).

Comment: @RundogieRundogie, если у Вас еще остались вопросы касательного этого кода - пишите здесь, я обновлю ответ дополнениями, если таковые появятся.

Comment: на самом деле интересовало другое. Код тот же самый но при указании выбрасывания в тернарном операторе исключения функция ломается. Почему?

Comment: @RundogieRundogie, если Вас именно _это_ интересовало - то почему я не вижу ни слова об этом в самом вопросе? Я не совсем понимаю, о чем идет речь - "код тот же самый, но при выбрасывании тернарного оператора" - получается, он уже не тот же самый?  :) Добавьте пример в свой вопрос - я посмотрю.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1048759/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc @isnullxbh

Comment: @RundogieRundogie, так, подождите :) Если Вы решили завести новый вопрос (я  Вас просил обновить этот), то сначала давайте разберемся с текущим - на этот вопрос я Вам ответил? Вам все понятно?

Comment: вы хотите чтобы я поставил вам галочку? Пожалуйста

Comment: @RundogieRundogie, я хочу, чтобы не было ситуаций, когда отвечаешь на вопрос, а потом оказывается, что и не вопрос это был вовсе, нужно совсем другое. А ставить «галочку» или нет - решаете Вы.

Comment: мой вопрос был задан в спешку поэтому вы нашли не ту ошибку которую я искал.

Answer (score 0):

Оба варианта формально "верны", но первый имеет неопределенное поведение.

В случае, когда ветви оператора `?:` имеют разные типы (ваш первый вариант), общий результат всего оператора `?:` будет являться prvalue. В такой ситуации о прямой привязке ссылки к операндам `?:` не может быть речи. Ссылка всегда будет привязываться к временному объекту, созданному на основе одного из операндов. Этот временный объект будет уничтожен по выходу из функции, в результате чего возвращенная ссылка окажется "подвисшей".

Во втором варианте обе ветви  `?:` являются lvalue одного и того же типа. Это значит, что и результат будет lvalue этого типа и, следовательно, ссылка будет привязана к этому lvalue напрямую, без создания каких либо промежуточных временных объектов.

Если вы уберете константность с возвращаемой ссылки, то первый вариант не будет даже компилироваться (по той же причине).