# Использование тернарной операции ведет к ошибкам?

Tags: c++

Бросает какое то другое исключение.

```
const std::string &getString(const numeration& l_enum)
{
    return (a > b)
        ? mass[static_cast<int>(l_enum)].m_name
        : throw Invalid("Some error");
}
```

Здесь же все работает как и предполагалось!

```
const std::string &getString(const numeration& l_enum)
{
    if(a>b)
    {
        return mass[static_cast<int>(l_enum)].m_name;
    }
    else throw Invalid("Some error");
}
```

Хотя обе функции работают как надо если срабатывает описанное исключение.

Comment: *Функция "ломается".* - ?

Comment: @Igor,не работает при условии что a >b

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Маленький гномик вылезает из компьютера и говорит: "Функция не работает."?

Comment: @Igor, точно, не подумал об этом. В общем вызывается исключение какое то другое и программа прекращает работу.

Comment: "вызывается исключение какое то другое" - Вы партизан на допросе? Какое?

Comment: @Igor, а вы не можете сообразить что именно это меня и интересует?

Comment: Вопрос бессмыслен без указания точного типа `mass[static_cast<int>(l_enum)].m_name`.

Comment: @Ant , std::string

Comment: Какой компилятор?

Comment: @AnT, Visual Studio 2017 community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы наткнулись на баг в компиляторе (присутствует в [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64372) и в VS2017). Современный стандарт С++ [требует](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#2.1), чтобы в такой ситуации в операторе `?:` сохранялись тип и категория значения не-throw операнда

> The second or the third operand (but not both) is a (possibly parenthesized) throw-expression; the result is of the type and **value category** of the other.

Т.е. ссылка в такой ситуации должна привязываться напрямую к `mass[static_cast<int>(l_enum)].m_name`. Однако GCC в такой ситуации отказывается сохранять категорию значения операнда и превращает его в prvalue. В результате создается временный объект, к которому и будет привязана ссылка. Этот временный объект уничтожается по выходу из функции, о чем GCC сообщает предупреждением

```
warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
```

а VS2017

```
warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary
```

Возвращенная из функции ссылка в результате оказывается "подвисшей".

Clang свободен от этого бага. Эксперимент показывает, что VS2019 тоже свободна от этого бага.

Смена требований стандарта в этой ситуации произошла, если я не ошибаюсь, в С++14. В С++11 результат такого `?:` являлся prvalue, то есть ваша функция и не должна была работать правильно по вышеописанным причинам. Но начиная с С++14 с ней уже все в порядке.

См. [DR#1550](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1550), [DR#1560](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1560) и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53328407/value-category-of-conditional-operator

Другими словами, ваш вариант с `?:` должен был вызвать вопросы и сомнения такого толка и у вас самого, ибо еще "относительно недавно" падение вашей функции было вполне легальным.

Comment: Скорее всего? То есть это может быть и другая ошибка?

Comment: @Rundogie Rundogie: "Скорее всего" я написал, когда не знал, каким компилятором вы пользуетесь. А теперь все ясно.

Comment: К сожалению я как и многие другие программирую не по стандарту C++.